# Spring obtain an IP address from an RPC encoded Webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, spring, axis

So I am currently connecting to an RPC encoded webservice which uses Axis. Unfortunately changing from Axis is not an option, my application is currently using Spring.

My Spring config currently looks something similar to:

```
<bean id="appWebServiceClient"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceInterface"
        value="app.test.stubs.external.Gateway_PortType"/>
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="${app.url}"/>
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="${app.namespace}"/>
    <property name="serviceName" value="${app.servicename}"/>
    <property name="portName" value="${app.portname}"/>
    <property name="lookupServiceOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="customPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="axis.connection.timeout">
                <value type="java.lang.Integer">${app.timeout}</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
```

I am then injecting the above bean into a processing class which has an instansiation of `Gateway_PortType` (Stub interface generated by Axistools) which I then use to actually invoke methods on the server I am trying to connect to.

My problem is I need to automatically get the IP of the server I am sending to i.e of the instansiated `Gateway_PortType`. Any ideas on how to do this? I have tried casting the injected bean to `JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean` / `org.apache.axis.client.Stub` to try and get the IP or Hostname but to no avail. If I try to get `.getClass().getName()` of the instansiated object all i get is `$Proxy44` or something similar. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Axis but I do know a little about Spring and its proxy behavior.  For some reason Spring must be creating a proxy around appWebServiceClient.  This could be because of `@Transactional` annotations, it could be because you explicitly declare a proxy or it could be because you have aspects in place (I'm sure there are other reasons as well).

Whenever you declare your proxies you are (perhaps implicitly) also specifying which "kind" of proxy you want.  There are two kinds of proxies.  The first (and typically default) is JDK-based proxies.  The second is CGLIB proxies.  For example, many people enable proxies by adding the following line to their application context.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

There is some hidden meaning to the above line.  By adding that line you are configuring spring to use JDK proxies whenever possible.  If you wanted to use CGLIB proxies then you would say:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

A comprehensive list of the differences between CGLIB proxies and JDK proxies are beyond the scope of this answer.  The main important difference is that CGLIB proxies work on classes and JDK proxies work on interfaces.

Since you are using JDK proxies and your class implements at least one interface then the proxy that spring creates will only encompass the interfaces of your class.  This means the generated class prototype would look like:

```
public class $Proxy44 implements interfaceA, interfaceB, interfaceC {
```

Obviously $Proxy44 cannot be casted to JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean or any base classes (e.g. org.apache.axis.client.Stub).  It could however be casted to any interfaces.  So if you can get the IP address from casting to an interface (e.g. javax.xml.rpc.Stub) then you should go that route.

If none of the interfaces will provide the IP address then off the top of my head you could either add a new interface to your stub class (which may not be possible since it is auto generated), use CGLIB proxies (there could be other implications to doing so), not proxy the class (the feasibility of this depends on why you are doing the proxy in the first place), or access the proxy target (not even sure this is possible and if it is it would be extremely dangerous.  I would not recommend it).

There are probably some other solutions too but without knowing more it is difficult to say.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pace, as per your suggestion I managed to cast the proxy class to javax.rmi.Remote however I have made no progress on retrieving the IP Address or hostname. Basically my code looks something as follows:

public String getIPAddress(Object stub)
 {
  java.rmi.Remote remote = (Remote)  stub;
  String hostIpAddress = ((org.apache.axis.client.Stub) remote)._getService().getWSDLDocumentLocation().getHost();
}   
From my experience with Axis the above is the correct way to get the hostname or Ip however still getting a class cast exception.